# VBA - Expose specific userform event in class module

Tags: visual-studio, vba, excel

I have an Excel VBA project that I'm working on, using a class module to manipulate certain userform activity in the project.

As far as I am aware (correct me if I'm wrong) the `Userform_QueryClose()` event is not exposed to the class module when using the `WithEvents` declaration on a variable.

---

*example: (I don't think this is possible)*

```
Private WithEvents classForm As MSForms.UserForm

Private Sub classForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Boolean, CloseMode As Integer)
    '// Event code here...
End Sub
```

---

On this assumption, I was wondering if it's possible to handle these 'extra' events using an add-in built in Visual Studio using VB.Net or similar?

(For clarity - my question is just asking if this is *possible* as a solution, if it can be done I will research how to do so separately so I'm not trying to generate any debate around best practice on the matter.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about, adding a custom event in the class and then in the original Userform inside the QueryClose event, raising this custom event.

Comment: There are about 30 userforms in the project - I'm trying to use the class module to centralize the code as opposed to copying the routine into each userform. Although it's looking more the case that this is what I'll have to do :(

Comment: @cyboashu Yes, this is my fall back if I can't find another option - thanks for the suggestion.